# How to use tabs instead of spaces for other than indenting in Eclipse neon?

Tags: eclipse, tabs, whitespace, spaces

I want to use the tab character rather than the set of spaces in every opportunity that presents itself.  In Eclipse helios, this was not a problem.  Eclipse did not attempt to change anything but the indentation, and that setting was settable.  Now, I will go from:

...

(tab)/**

(tab)*(cursor)

...

then I will hit the tab character with my cursor where shown, resulting in:

...

(tab)/**

(tab)*(space)(space)(cursor)

...

Anyone know why this might be and how to prevent it?  The single most annoying application of this problem is when I copy a tab character and paste it somewhere else, it shows up as a set of spaces.

Note: I can overcome this via ctrl+f and replace, but that is so annoying to use after the fact. I am looking for something that prevents that from being necessary in the first place

Comment: Have you already reviwed the `Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter > Edit ... > Indentation` preferences ? Show us how you got them right now.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that.  It does not have the extent of the desired effect.  It affects neither of the specified circumstances.